# 502 Bad Gateway on my Django app hosted on Elastic beanstalk using Application Load balancer

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-application-load-balancer

I am having this issue with my Django web app

502 Bad Gateway Nginx/1.20.0

This error occurs whenever I am trying to view any of the task_submitted models or if I want to add another one.

Sometimes it won't display this error, it will work perfectly and sometimes it will display this error.

The app is hosted on the elastic beanstalk.

I have checked my Django app terminal for any error log but I can't find any logs there.

If you need any other information about this just let me know and I will provide it.

The Nginx/error.log:

564 2023/04/11 07:43:24 [error] 3557#3557: *71997 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: ip adderess, server: request: "GET /social/director/admin/socialearningapp/task_submitted/143586/change/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/social/director/admin/socialearningapp/task_submitted/143586/change/", host: | "socialearning.org", referrer: "https://socialearning.org/social/director/admin/socialearningapp/task_submitted/"

[My model which I am having issues with when viewing or creating new objects screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNDVh.jpg)

[The error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YcgS.jpg)

[Ngnix/error.log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIoSW.png)

Where can I get the error log and fix the issue?

Comment: This seems more like an Nginx or a Beanstalk error, more so than a Django Error. Nginx logs are usually located in `/var/logs/nginx/` maybe there's hints in there.. I'm not sure where the Beanstalk logs are, I've never used it

Comment: @Nealium i have included the error.log image

Comment: Interesting. I take it back, Django problem. How are you running Django in the server? Are you doing Gunicorn or Uwsgi?- looks like whatever it is is dropping the connection too early, most likely a default setting needs to be tweaked.